# Ember Data filtering firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, ember.js, ember-data, filtering

I am currently trying to filter data from a firebase DB using ember data. I would like the data to be filtered as the user is typing in the search box based on the data attribute name.

This is currently the model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
    export default DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr(),
        requirements: DS.attr(),
        skills: DS.attr()
    });
```

This is currently the route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        var obj = this.store.findAll('quest');
        return obj;
    }
});
```

The current firebase DB is filled with dummy data but also has the automatically generated ID that is generated by using the push command, not sure if this poses any issues. I have tried filtering the data using filter in the route but had no success and this is my first time using ember and firebase. Thank you.

Edit:
I have created a controller to attempt to filter the data. The data is being passed to the controller through an action, but I can't seem to actually parse the data. Here is the controller code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        filter() {
            var model = this.get('model');
            console.log(model);
            this.toggleProperty('isExpanded');
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
I have updated the controller and can properly search the firebase DB but it is not reading my search value properly.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        var search = JSON.stringify(params.search);
        console.log(search);
        return this.store.query('quest', {
            startAt:  search,
            orderBy: 'title',
            limitToLast: 10
        });
    }
});
```

if I change the "startAt: search" line to a hardcoded line, it filters properly. Any ideas?

Edit 3: 
Attaching an image to show what the page looks like on load, as well as the logging of the search to show that its being passed. 
[console on the load of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4tcz.png)
here is the updated code in the controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    queryParams: ['search'],
    search: ""
});
```

Comment: you can try filterBy method like `this.get('model').filterBy('name','typedvalue')`

Comment: @kumkanillam I attempted that within the controller but it is returning an empty array.

Comment: Is the controller and route file name is same. update your attempted code in question

Comment: @kumkanillam I have updated the controller code on my edit 2, thank you. Still having some trouble though.

Comment: @kumkanillam I replied below but wasn't able to tag you for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [Query Parameters docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/query-params/). 
define `queryParams` property in route and controller file to get the value in model hook.

So in route.js define `queryParams` like the below

```
queryParams: {
    search: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  }
```

and in controller file,

```
queryParams: ['search'],
search: null
```

If you can just set `search` property then it will [start full transition](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/query-params/#toc_opting-into-a-full-transition)

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the controller, but yeah it has those lines of code and I also added the query params to the route, still nothing. It is properly logging all of the information in the console, but the search isn't going.

Comment: @pvelasqu Please include the code where are you setting `this.set('search','typedvalue')` ?. this part of the code is very important to trigger full transition

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean. I do not think I have that anywhere. I am trying to pull the value from the search within the route and trying to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: if the url contains `?search=typedvalue` then in model hook you will get value `params.search`. Do you get this in your model hook for the first time when route is loading

Comment: Yes I do, I am console logging it as well to ensure that it's passed. I can attach an image if you'd like.

Comment: I've attached the image as an edit on the main post showing that the search is logged.

Comment: We need to look at all the code related to this identify the exact issue. one more option is you can isolate that problem in ember-twiddle easily.  I created [sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b10b00f4cf35be5b37a6acccfb48796a?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C&route=%2F%3Fsearch%3Daaaaa) to illustrate what I meant. When you type value in search box I am just setting `search` property then it will start loading routes

Comment: I have the exact same code there except on the route which is just contacting the database.

Comment: You can update the exact code in twiddle so that we can identify that issue easily.

Comment: Ok so I got the code refreshing actually, but for some reason when I search it will return everything below that specific item in Firebase. So if I search for item 1 it will return 1 to n, but if I search 2 it will return 2 to n and leave one out. Refreshing and filtering is working, just not properly filtering.

Comment: Ok so I looked at the firebase documentation and added an upper range

"The \uf8ff character used in the query above is a very high code point in the Unicode range. Because it is after most regular characters in Unicode, the query matches all values that start with a b."

Comment: Glad you got it.. I am not used firebase not even once

Comment: Thank you so much!